# Ubuntu 12.04 secondary IP externally inaccesible

Tags: 12.04, iptables, ip, tomcat7

I have added a secondary IP to my virtual server, Ubuntu 12.04 **running in OpenVZ virtual host**. I used `ip addr add xx.xxx.168.95/32 label venet0:1 dev venet0`.

When I do ifconfig the IP shows up below lo, venet0 and venet0:0:

```
venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
inet addr:xx.xxx.168.95  P-t-P:xx.xxx.168.95  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

There are issues reaching the secondary IP externally. Local access works fine and I'm using a tomcat instance with ipbased virtual hosting. Locally the 2 sites are served correctly. Externally I can only reach the one on the main IP.
Google DNS resolves the domain name pointing to the secondary IP in question and on the Ubuntu machine I've added them to hosts as well.

I can't reach the secondary IP externally, however, not even with ping. It would seem I need to add something to make the secondary IP available to the internet.

What am I missing here?

***UPDATE***

So, I found the concept of IP Alias interesting. Here's my "interfaces" file:

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

```
auto venet0
iface venet0 inet manual
    up ifconfig venet0 up
    up ifconfig venet0 0
    up route add default dev venet0
    down route del default dev venet0
    down ifconfig venet0 down


iface venet0 inet6 manual
    up ifconfig venet0 add yyyy:yyy:5::4db/0
    down ifconfig venet0 del yyyy:yyy:5::4db/0

    up /sbin/ip -6 route add 2000::/3 dev venet0
auto venet0:0
iface venet0:0 inet static
    address xx.xxx.168.175
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

This file also states not to edit that file, but rather to create an "interfaces.tail" file with additional rules:

```
    auto venet0:1
iface venet0:1 inet static
    address xx.xxx.168.95
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Making this file isn't enough however. I need to restart the networking and I tried with `/etc/init.d/networking restart` but that "Failed to bring up venet0". So I rebooted. The interfaces.tail isn't read.

Comment: If you say its fine withing your network, it maybe the firewall thats blocking it for some reason. You can try to temporarily Disable it by using this command 'sudo iptables -F' --- as per documentation here ---  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: Thanks for your response, Tasos. I tried iptables -L and get  `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination` which to me looks like I have no IPtables active? I also tried the -F option and I can't ping the secondary IP.

Comment: It would seem my approach doesn't work and I need to investigate IP aliasing with the ip command.

Comment: I don't know much about OpeVVZ but after reading some Documentation the veth Net device sounds a bit more friendly as it has more features --- http://openvz.org/Differences_between_venet_and_veth  ---  But dont quote me on any ofthis. I checked the links by "Feature veth venet"

Comment: See the update for details. I don't seem to control interfaces so I seem stuck with venet.

Comment: OK, problem partly solved. Thank you Tasos for bringing me to the right sources. It's' only with veth that you need to set the additional address on the client. With venet you do it from the virtual host, in my case the web interface for my virtual server where I simply assigned the IP and it was added to interfaces. 

Now, I can ping both addresses. The web server isn't responding properly, but now the IPs are working at least.

Add an answer clarifying this Tasos and I'll credit your answer. You did me a great service.

Comment: Excellent, i'm glad those links helped. Ok Ill add the Comment with the Links. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about OpenVZ, but after reading some documentation, the veth Net device sounds a bit more friendly as it has more features:

- http://openvz.org/Differences_between_venet_and_veth

But don't quote me on any of this.

I checked the links by "Feature veth venet"

Original answer by Tasos